# Import Caffe: One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: python, opencv, caffe

I got this when trying to import caffe into Spyder(python2.7).
Caffe was successfully installed and it went through test.
Any idea how to solve it?

> objc[3163]: Class `CVWindow` is implemented in both
>   /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib and
>   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>       objc[3163]: Class `CVView` is implemented in both /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib and
>   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib.
>     One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>       objc[3163]: Class `CVSlider` is implemented in both /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib and
>   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>       objc[3163]: Class `CaptureDelegate` is implemented in both /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib and
>   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.